# How can you get a webm file without headers to play video and audio?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

Right now I have webm files that are missing the header information so they don't play. How can I fix them so that they play? My only hack is to get a small webm file with header information and prepend the file, then encode to mp4 and mp3.

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm output.mp4
[matroska,webm @ 0x13481be00] Format matroska,webm detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[matroska,webm @ 0x13481be00] EBML header parsing failed
kyle.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Example file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j21wxHyQimMorWU99MJx--4YhgSimkp7/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the header?

Comment: I got the same errors for a mkv file. The problem wasn't that the file was missing the header, but that it couldn't have been read properly. I open the file as binary and there were some extra stuff at the beginning of the file. I deleted them and then it played just filne.

Comment: Were you able to do that programatically? I think my issue was headers missing tho because if I grab a file with headers then it works just fine.

Comment: I just opened it with Vim and compared it with an intact file.

Comment: You may improve the chances for getting an answer, by sharing `input.webm` video file. We like to test the solution before posting an answer, and we can't do that without the video file.

Comment: Okay I have added a file

Comment: wait... you have the necessary header? attach it to the question as well. then it's just a matter of combining them with any programming language, from python through bash / powershell. hell even BATCH will do.

Comment: I have a file that won't play. Basically record with mediarecorder, split into chunks, and try to play any file except the first - you can't. I want to try and make that individual file work.

Comment: @John did you later found a solution?

Comment: @Anthony No I haven't

Comment: i ended up using mimeType="video/webm; codecs="vp9,opus" for MediaRecorder, then live streaming it back to the client with the same codecs as most browsers supports it. Meanwhile i stores those chunks by appending it to a single file. After live streaming is done, i convert the either files to mp4 so the user can watch later.

Comment: For me it only happens sometimes. Its like there's a corrupt header or its missing altogether. But I know there is video and audio. The file is large I just don't know how I can see it.